# Why do i have to set the Parent Entity when subclassing and abstract entity?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, inheritance, core-data, subclass

The problem I'm having is that i can't assign to an attribute of a subclass unless i've set the subclassed entity's Parent Entity property to the entity of the abstract superclass.

In XCode 4.0.2, this is the Parent Entity property to which i'm referring:

[image]

What i don't get is that i thought a Parent Entity is intended for parent-child relationships between entities and the object relationships are simply captured by the class definitions.

## Example

**Entities A, B and C:**

- A is an abstract entity of type A with attributes:

  - y : string
  - z : string
- B is an entity of type A with no attributes
- C is an entity of type A with no attributes

**Classes A, B and C:**

```
@interface A : NSManagedObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * y;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * z;

@interface B : A {
}
@interface C : A {
}
```

**The Problem**

If i don't set the Parent Entity for entities B and C to be entity A, then when i try:

```
NSEntityDescription *be = [[mom entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"B"];
B *b = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:be
                insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc];

b.y = @"test"; // <<-- This line causes the following error:
```

I get:

```
-[NSManagedObject setY:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

If i set the Parent Entity, it seems to work except that entity persisted to the store seems to be A instead of B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you remember to set the class for entity B to class B? If yes, you should take a look at the type of the pointer that's assigned to `b`... is it in fact a B*? It looks like it's probably a NSManagedObject* based on the error you're getting, and according to the docs for [`-initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/initWithEntity%3ainsertIntoManagedObjectContext%3a)...

> The dynamically-generated subclass
>   will be based on the class specified
>   by the entity, so specifying a custom
>   class in your model will supersede the
>   class passed to alloc.

...I think you should be getting a B* if your model is configured correctly.